# software to emulate a blackboard over internet

Tags: windows, microsoft-paint

I need to tutor my brother on a particular topic. We live in different geographical areas. We use g-talk to do the same. We do not have web-cam's to enable video chat.

The tutoring will involve a lot of off-the-cuff illustrations. I am hence searching for a suitable software which will emulate a blackboard over an internet connection. I need the software to enable sharing of a common canvas on which I can draw, write and point to. Say a Microsoft paint canvas on internet.

Could you point out a suitable software? Google is not of being help at the moment as I suspect that I am not specifying my search criteria properly.

Comment: you might try searching on the term "whiteboard" instead of "blackboard".  i'm fairly sure there are collaboration apps that will do what you want.  at the most basic, you could use VNC or another screen sharing solution would let you share desktops, then open MS Paint on the shared desktop and use that.  but i think there are easier methods.

Comment: The trick was searching for "whiteboard". Thanks.

Comment: they use "whiteboard" because it's a more modern.  blackboards are the old ones you write on with chalk.  whiteboards are the new ones you write on with dry-erase markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend FlockDraw. It's flash, not java based, and to create a unique place for you and someone else to use, you simply point your browser to a URL like this:

http://flockdraw.com/SuperUser

No login required.

Answer (score 1):

A suitable online collaboration tool is http://www.scriblink.com/.

Searching for "whiteboard" along with keywords, "online collaboration tool" as quack quixote suggested above gives a lot of solutions.